# テキストエリアの右下にある//を消したい(リサイズを禁止したい)

Tags: html, css

#### 前提・実現したいこと

テキストエリアの右下にある//を消したいです。

これです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

調べたのですが見つかりませんでした((+_+))

マルチポスト
[テラテイル](https://teratail.com/questions/56715?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

cssにこれを追加しました。

```
resize: none;
```

参考
http://css-happylife.com/archives/2011/0725_0838.php